# Change welcome page shown when you go to https://myExample.sharepoint.com to a specific site

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-collection, navigation, homepage

I have a Sharepoint Online site that my users access by going to https://myCompanyName.sharepoint.com.

I have 9 sites in total. I want the "Home" site to be the default landing site when the user goes to the URL. When creating the SPO instance, I decided to create a separate "Home" site to better control access and to keep it separate from the default welcome page. Now, however, I want rid of that welcome page, as it currently sits blank doing nothing:

[image]

I've read about setting individual *Pages* to be the HomePage, but changing the site that the user lands on is different and I wonder if it's even possible.

If not, is there a workout? Maybe a way to automatically redirect the user to the Home site?

Comment: The Home site is different site collection?

Comment: Home is a different Site - isn't a Site Collection what my 9 Sites (Home, HR, Customer Support etc.) reside in?

Comment: It might help if you can provide the URL of the site that you want to be the "Home" site.

Comment: I have to keep the company name private but the redacted URL of what I want to be the home site is: https://myCompany.sharepoint.com/sites/Home

Comment: The only way that I can think of doing this is to add a redirect on the myCompany.sharepoint.page to redirect to the /sites/home site.